# Why do I have to qualify the namespace for a function passed a typedef of the functions templated parameter type?

Tags: c++, templates

In this example why do I need to qualify the function call B::F() with its namespace?  As the typedef of QF should match the type Q as I thought it was an alias for it, not really a new type?

Is there an elegant way around this that doesn't require a using statement in every function body?

```
namespace A
{
    template<class T> struct V {};
    template<class T> struct Q {};


    typedef Q<float> QF;


    template<class T>
    inline void F(V<T> v) {}



    namespace B
    {
        template<class T>
        inline void F(Q<T> q) {}
    }


    namespace C
    {
        void Test();
    }
}


using namespace A;
using namespace A::B;


void A::C::Test()
{
    QF q;


    //  using namespace A::B;   //  Uncomment will work


    F(q);       //  Error, tries A::F() and can't find B::F()
    B::F(q);     //  Ok it uses B::F() as intended
}


int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you put cout in your functions you realize that when you call F(q) it actually calls A::B::F instead of A::F. Both calls would print A::B::F

Comment: There is no error when I try to build it http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8fa3154cab7203a6

Comment: I could not reproduce the error for `F(q)` on either GCC or clang.

Comment: I am using VS2017, will check to see if I made an error in simplifying the problem and copy paste or it is an issue with compiler...

Comment: So you didn't actually test the code posted here?

Comment: ok I made a mistake when simplifying and testing - the updated code in the question should show the error - which has also made me realise its probably to do with the namespace of the function Test() not inheriting the using statements in the global space which I assumed it would

Comment: You definitely hit an interesting point here, your example may be simplified a lot:
https://godbolt.org/z/y3aM5L
No templates and still the same problem, the global using directive is definitely seen as otherwise df is not visible, but this does not help with f. But it's getting really interesting when you comment out the global directive and uncomment the local one. Then the compilers in trunk version differ in interpretation.

Comment: Hmm and I get the original problem in both the latest VS2017 and VS2019.  I'm not sure what the standard says is supposed to happen here but if it is supposed to be an error it seems an odd decision.  Especially if you recreated a similar issue by removing the typedef and template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to show in what ways clang interprets the draft differently than gcc and msvc. When you call `F(q)` inside the definition of void `A::C::Test()`, the compiler tries to look up the name `F` in the scopes in which that call is made, and will stop looking for larger scopes as soon as that name (name, not particular overload) is found. The body of void `A::C::Test()` is inside the namespace `C` which is inside `A` which is inside the global namespace. So when you write the using directive in the global scope, the relevant passage in the standard [basic.lookup.unqual]:

> 1. In all the cases listed in [basic.lookup.unqual], the scopes are searched for a declaration in the order listed in each of the
>      respective categories; name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is
>      found for the name. If no declaration is found, the program is
>      ill-formed.
> 2. The declarations from the namespace nominated by a using-directive become visible in a namespace enclosing the using-directive; see
>      [namespace.udir]. For the purpose of the unqualified name lookup rules
>      described in [basic.lookup.unqual], the declarations from the
>      namespace nominated by the using-directive are considered members of
>      that enclosing namespace.

by point 2 implies that the name `F` (coming from `A::B::F`) is visible as if it was declared in the global scope, but by point 1 name lookup will find a name `F` sooner, in namespace `A` and will not look further. So it only finds `void F(V<T> v)` and this declaration is not fit for the call.

The more interesting story is with the using directive put *inside* the body of the function. The difference in approach is whether the definition of `void A::C::Test()` (which is also a declaration) appears in the global namespace or in namespace `A::C`. If you take the view that this is the global namespace (as clang apparently does), then the namespace enclosing the using-directive written inside the function is the global namespace and we are back to the explanation above. But if you believe that it appears in namespace `A::C`, then you bring in (among others) the declaration of `void F(Q<T>)` into `A::C` and regular lookup finds it.

A bonus observation is why you would still be able to call `F(V<double>{})` since now the declaration `void F(Q<T>)` is in a narrower scope - and the answer is argument-dependent lookup, the namespace where `V<T>` is declared is going to be looked at too.

That's a story to scare the learner, but if you want practical guidance, do not use the shortcut with namespaces, use

```
namespace A::C 
{
void Test()
{
...
}
}
```

so that the namespace in which it is declared is not subject to debate and put using namespace A::B; either in namespace scope or in function scope.
(And I'll try to figure out what was the real intended scope of the `void A::C::Test()` declaration-definition with wiser people).